# How do I auto-mount a network share from a Linux Samba server on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, samba, file-sharing

So I started working for a company that has a Windows Small Business Server 2003 as the domain controller with the workstations being Windows 7.

We have a Linux server with Samba installed, which acts like a file server. The current setup has us logging into the workstation as the user and mapping the drive, because we have a single account for the Linux server.

Is there a way for the network drive to auto-mount for each of the users, regardless of the workstation they're on?

Answer (score 0):

Just map the drive from explorer and check the reconnect option.

or from a command line:

**net use z: \Server\Share /P:Yes**